# Vue 3 - Is it possible to make properties of an external class reactive, without modifying the external class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue 3, I would like to display some of the properties from an external class inside of a Vue component, and have the component react to changes. The class is responsible for updating its own properties.

I was able to achieve this in Vue 2, by just creating a plain object which referenced the class properties I wanted to observe and putting that object into Vuex. From there, whenever the external class updated one of its properties, the vuex copy would also change.

In Vue 3, i'm using the reactive function from the composition api which I think creates a copy of the original object, which is probably why it doesn't work.

Is there any way to achieve this in Vue 3?

Here's a very simplified example of what I have tried. So I would want the count variable to refresh when it is updated by test.increment

```
<template>
    <div>{{count}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, reactive, ref } from 'vue';

let test = {
    count: 1,
    increment(){
        this.count++;
    }
};

setTimeout(()=>{test.increment()}, 2000);

export default defineComponent({
    setup(){
        return {
            count: ref(test.count)
        };
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... Anything that you pass as a property should already be reactive?

Comment: I've added a simple example of what I have tried. Hopefully that makes my question a bit clearer.

Comment: this object serves only as initial value, it'll not be reactive

Comment: Have you tried `count: ref(1)` or `count: reactive(1)`? Or even making the whole test object reactive?